Display in a tooltip a calculated value based on previously aggregated values in vega-lite deneb visualization
I'm displaying a bar chart, showing aggregated values per month for two columns (actuals, budget), i.e. sum per month. I would like to display in a tooltip calculated ratio from those two newly created columns 1-(actual/budget)*100. I see those columns are in data_0 table in powerbi/deneb, called sum_Budget and sum_Actual.
I don't understand how should I refer to those newly created columns. Will appreciate any hint!
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Project": "A", "Budget": 100, "Actual": 20, "Month": "Jun"},
      {"Project": "B", "Budget": 150, "Actual": 30, "Month": "Jun"},
      {"Project": "A", "Budget": 120, "Actual": 40, "Month": "Jul"},
      {"Project": "B", "Budget": 150, "Actual": 70, "Month": "Jul"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "xOffset": 0,
        "size": 18,
        "tooltip": true,
        "opacity": 1,
        "color": "tomato"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Actual", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"},
        "x": {
          "field": "Month",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": ""},
          "scale": {"domain": ["Jun", "Jul"]}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "xOffset": 0,
        "size": 5,
        "opacity": 0.6,
        "color": "darkblue"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Budget",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "x": {"field": "Month", "type": "nominal"},
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "Budget",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Budget: ",
            "format": ","
          },
          {
            "field": "Actual",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Actual: ",
            "format": ","
          },
          {"field": "ratio"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

example in Vega-Lite editor

found a solution myself Open the Chart in the Vega Editor
